# bokeh errors: import error, color gradient error, JS feedback and browser selection

Tags: python, bokeh, importerror

```
from bokeh.core.state import State
from bokeh.io import _CommsHandle, push_notebook
 from bokeh.embed import notebook_div


        ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-4-b18f604973b2> in <module>()
        ----> 1 from bokeh.core.state import State
              2 from bokeh.io import _CommsHandle, push_notebook
              3 from bokeh.embed import notebook_div



        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.core.state'


from add_on import output_notebook, show_figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook 
from bokeh.plotting import Figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource


output_notebook()
```

The bokeh.core.state import State is the only import that doesnt work. The python versions are the same and there is no file with bokeh in the name. Anyone have any idea whats going on?

FYI: this I'm trying to create a bokeh graph where I can select data points with the lasso and get them back into jupyter notebook to for analysis. Here is the code I have to create the graphs, would love some insight on getting the datapoints back (assuming with Javascript).

```
    import matplotlib as mpl

    import bokeh.plotting as bpl
    import bokeh.models as bmo

    from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, ContinuousColorMapper


    TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select,"

    def graph_bokeh(algorithm,coordinate_df,metric):


        source = bpl.ColumnDataSource(coordinate_df)

    #     color_map = bmo.CategoricalColorMapper(factors=coordinate_df[metric].unique())

    #     colors = {1:'red',0:'grey'}
        if metric != 'LengthOfStayDaysNBR':
            color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(palette=['red','grey'])#,factors = metric)
        else:
            color_mapper = ContinuousColorMapper(palette='Magma256', low=min(coordinate_df[metric]), high=max(coordinate_df[metric]))




        bokeh_graph = figure(width=250, height = 250, title = '{}'.format(str(algorithm)[:3]),tools=TOOLS)

        bokeh_graph.scatter('x-{}'.format(str(algorithm)[:3]),'y-{}'.format(str(algorithm)[:3])\
                            ,color={'field': metric,'transform': color_mapper}\
                            , legend = metric, source = source)



        return bokeh_graph




    for metric in metrics:

        bokeh_graphs = {}
        for i,algorithm in enumerate(algorithms):


             bokeh_graphs[i+1] = graph_bokeh(algorithm,df_algs,metric)

    graph_list = []
    for k,v in bokeh_graphs.items():

        if k%2 == 1 and k!= len(bokeh_graphs):
            graph_list.append([bokeh_graphs[k],bokeh_graphs[k+1]])
        elif k%2 == 1 and k == len(bokeh_graphs):
            graph_list.append([bokeh_graphs[k],None])

    p = gridplot(graph_list)
    show(p)
```

(sorry for three/four part question):
I'm having trouble with the color gradient for the lengthofstay metric (a third column i would like to color the x/y coordinates by)

```
        color_mapper = ContinuousColorMapper(palette='Magma256', low=min(coordinate_df[metric]), high=max(coordinate_df[metric]))
```

always outputs the blue color gradient (no matter what palette i specify)

Lastly, 
the graphs open in internet explorer, and i would like chrome.

```
import webbrowser
```

webbrowser.register("chrome", None)

doesnt seem to work,

neither does 
show(browser='chrome')

Answer (score 0):

That module moved to `bokeh.io` some time ago:

```
In [3]: from bokeh.io.state import State

In [4]:
```

Can I ask why you think you need to use `State` directly? It's not something I would really consider necessary for normal users to ever use. It mostly exists to facilitate testing.

Comment: The overall goal is to create a bokeh graph that has the lasso tool that feeds either 1) the x/y coordinates back or 2) the indexes back into python.... so not absolutely necessary.